# Bootstrap Modal: Wrong Content being displayed

Tags: html, ejs

I have a for loop in a for loop. The first for loop goes through every building, and the second goes through every building with a prerequisite (only want to display buildings with prerequisites). Once that's done, I get 4 buildings displayed, each with it's own name, id, description and a build option. My problem is that when I click build, my modal pops up, but only shows content for the first building, regardless of which building build button I click. All I'm trying to display in the modal is the building name, resources required and a confirmation to build, but I only get data from the first building

```
 <div class="buildingsWithPrerequisite">
        <% for(var i = 0; i < newBuildingInfo.length; i++){ %>
            <% for(var j = 0; j < buildings_with_pre.length; j++){ %>
                <% if(newBuildingInfo[i][0] == buildings_with_pre[j][0]){ %>
                    <li>

                        <%= newBuildingInfo[j][0] %> <br>    <!-- Building Id -->
                        <%= newBuildingInfo[j][1] %> <br>    <!-- Building Name -->
                        <%= newBuildingInfo[j][2] %> <br>    <!-- Building Description -->

                        <!-- If requiremnt is met, color green, if not then red-->
                        <% if(buildings_with_pre[j][3] == false) { %>
                            <p style="color:red;">Requirement:
                            <%= buildings_with_pre[j][1] %>
                            Level <%= buildings_with_pre[j][2] %> </p>
                            <button class="btn btn-secondary" disabled>Build</button>
                        <% } else {%>
                            <p style="color:green;">Requirement: 
                            <%= buildings_with_pre[j][1] %>
                            Level <%= buildings_with_pre[j][2] %> </p>

                                <!-- Build Button with Popup-->
                                <form method="POST" action="/building-construct">
                                    <button type = "button" id="buildButton" class = "btn btn-success" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#constructWithPreBuilding" onclick="myfunc()"> Build </button>
                                    <div class="modal fade" id="constructWithPreBuilding" role="dialog" aria-labelledby= "exampleModalLabel">
                                        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                                            <div class="modal-content">
                                                <div class="modal-header">
                                                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel"> <%= newBuildingInfo[j][1] %> </h5> <!-- Building Name-->
                                                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                                </button>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="modal-body">
                                                    <%= newBuildingInfo[j][2] %> <br>    <!-- Building Description -->
                                                    Time: <br>
                                                    Cost: <br>
                                                </div>

                                                <div class="modal-footer">
                                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal"><!--Close--> <%= newBuildingInfo[j][0] %></button>
                                                <% if(can_build_with_pre[j] == true){ %>
                                                    <input type="hidden" name="buildingId" value = <%= buildings_with_pre[j][0] %>>
                                                    <input type="hidden" name="locationId" value = <%= location %>>
                                                    <input type = "Submit" class = "btn btn-success constructsBuilding" value = "Construct" > 
                                                <% } else { %>
                                                    <button type = "button" class="btn btn-secondary" disabled> Not Enough Resources</button>
                                                <% } %> 
                                                </div>

                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </form>
                        <% } %>
                    </li>
                <% } %>
            <% } %>
        <% } %>
        </div>
```

Comment: you have many modals with the same id. Give each modal a unique id

Comment: I only have 1 model though. I want the same model to get called every time, but just with different data, but for some reason I always get data from the first building

Answer (score 1):

From what i see, there is a problem with Ids. In every for loop your ejs code generates a modal for each building. As a result you have many modals containing different data, but with same Id `constructWithPreBuilding`. Furthermore, these modals are triggered by buttons with the same `id="buildButton"` and `data-target="#constructWithPreBuilding"`. 
Each modal and button should have unique id.
The first I'd change is to give each modal an id like Building Id

```
<div class="modal fade" id="<%= newBuildingInfo[j][0] %>" role="dialog" aria-labelledby= "exampleModalLabel">
```

and do the same changes on buttons

```
<button type = "button" id="bB<%= newBuildingInfo[j][0] %>" class = "btn btn-success" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#<%= newBuildingInfo[j][0] %>" onclick="myfunc()"> Build </button>
```

Hope that it helps you, or give you a similar idea.

Comment: I try implementing this and my modal no longer pops up. I get what your saying though about assigning each model a unique id. I think the problem is appending '#' with "<%= newBuildingInfo[j][0] %>" in my buttons data-target

Comment: try inspect element in your browser to see if Id are ok.